# Problemas para eliminar un registro con AJAX en Rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Al momento de eliminar un registro con `AJAX`, este lo elimina pero no actualiza la tabla con el registro eliminado, posiblemente tal vez este haciendo mal el `render` o me haga falta especificarle algo a mÁs a `destroy.js`, comparto mi código, espero puedan ayudarme:

*enterprises_controller.rb*

```
def destroy
    @enterprise_tag.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
       if @enterprise_tag.destroy
         format.html { redirect_to admin_dashboard_path, notice: "enterprise was remove successfully" }
         format.js { render partial: "list" }
       end
     end
end
```

**destroy.js.erb [ Tengo dudas en esta parte ]**

```
<% if @enterprise_tag.errors.empty? %>
  $("#items").append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'list') %>");
<% end %>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% if @enterprise_tags.any? %>
  <table id="items">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Fecha de creacion</td>
        <td colspan="2">Opciones</td>
      </tr>
      <% @enterprise_tags.each do |enterprise_tag| %>
        <%= render partial: "enterprise_tags/list", locals: { enterprise_tag:enterprise_tag } %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <% else %>
    <div class="callout small text-center">
      <span>No hay ningun registro disponible</span>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**_list.html.erb**

```
<tr>
  <td><%= link_to enterprise_tag_path(enterprise_tag), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "¿Desea eliminar este registro?" }, remote: true do %><i class="fi-trash"></i><% end %></td>
</tr>
```

**Consola del navegador**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Servidor de Rails**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas agregar un metodo en el destroy para que elimine con js cuando el ajax se ejecute.

agregar el uso de js en el metodo de destroy.

> controller

```
   def destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js
        end
      end
```

Agrega una class al `enterprise_tag` para que el js lo busque. Importante agregar el reote: true para que puedan hacer la funcion del ajax.

```
<%= link_to 'eliminar', enterprise_tag, method: :delete, data: { confirm: '¿Estas seguro?' }, :class=> "delete_",remote: true  %>
```

en el destroy.js.erb agrega el codigo que va a buscar el tr mas cercano a el `item` que vas a destruir.

> destroy.js.erb

```
$('.delete_').bind('ajax:success', function() {  
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
});
```